# Which group will migrate in this BVG oxidation?

Tags: organic-oxidation

[image]

I know that H has a higher migratory aptitude order than phenyl. But, in this case, the phenyl ring has electron donating groups attached to it which enhances its migratory aptitude. So, which group is more likely to migrate, H or phenyl?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6269/migratory-aptitude-in-baeyer-villiger-reaction

Comment: The Ph ring will migrate. B-V oxidation of aromatic aldehydes is routinely used to prepare phenols via formates, examples https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229145649_One-pot_synthesis_of_phenols_from_aromatic_aldehydes_by_Baeyer-Villiger_oxidation_with_H2O2_using_water-tolerant_Lewis_acids_in_molecular_sieves

Comment: The reaction is a Dakin oxidation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakin_oxidation