Intuition of the oxidation of alcohols?
I understand that primary alcohols oxidise to aldehydes and then to carboxylic acids, and secondary alcohols oxidise to ketones, while tertiary alcohols don't oxidise at all. However, I am struggling to understand why this is is the case. It seems that carbon - hydrogen bonds are needed for oxidation, but it is unclear to me why. If we had a carbon - carbon bond why can't this be oxidised? I have read an explanation that says oxidation can be thought of as the number of bonds to an oxygen, but this doesn't really make sense to me. Could someone start from the beginning and explain oxidation and why we need specifically a carbon - hydrogen bond to have oxidation? It's easy memorising this but it doesn't make any intuitive sense to me. Perhaps my lack of understanding comes from what oxidation really is in the context of alcohols.

I suggest studying two separate topics. What is oxidation. What are reaction mechanisms of alcohol oxidations. C-C bonds break during oxidation too, but usually at very different conditions via different mechanisms.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/aldehydes-are-easily-oxidised-but-ketones-are-not

The carbon - carbon bond is very strong, which is the basis of organic chemistry. Additionally, the hydrogen can often react with the oxygen atoms on an oxidising agent and be lost through dehydration.
Notably however, there are oxidation’s which occur without a carbon-hydrogen bond being broken, such as the Baeyer-Villiger oxidation.

Tertiary alcohols do oxidise, though it is true that is tends to be more difficult than the oxidation of primary or secondary alcohols
